# Uncaught init() exception created by servlet [REST Service] in application [webservices]: java.lang.IllegalArgumentException

Tags: java, jackson, jersey, websphere, websphere-liberty

I have JAX-RS based REST API running on WebSphere Application Server Version 8.5.5.9 Liberty Profile. It got below dependencies. Webservices worked fine.
[image]

Due to some security vulneribilites in Jackson Library I updated to 2.11 version. Now my dependencies look like this:
[image]

Now When I start my server or make API call I see the below error message in log:

```
[6/8/20 16:47:14:929 CDT] 0000004d id=         com.ibm.ws.webcontainer.servlet.ServletWrapper               E init SRVE0271E: Uncaught init() exception created by servlet [REST Service] in application [webservices]: java.lang.IllegalArgumentException
at jersey.repackaged.org.objectweb.asm.ClassReader.<init>(ClassReader.java:170)
at jersey.repackaged.org.objectweb.asm.ClassReader.<init>(ClassReader.java:153)
at jersey.repackaged.org.objectweb.asm.ClassReader.<init>(ClassReader.java:424)
at com.sun.jersey.spi.scanning.AnnotationScannerListener.onProcess(AnnotationScannerListener.java:138)
at com.sun.jersey.core.spi.scanning.JarFileScanner.scan(JarFileScanner.java:97)
at com.sun.jersey.spi.scanning.servlet.WebAppResourcesScanner$1.f(WebAppResourcesScanner.java:94)
at com.sun.jersey.core.util.Closing.f(Closing.java:71)
at com.sun.jersey.spi.scanning.servlet.WebAppResourcesScanner.scan(WebAppResourcesScanner.java:92)
at com.sun.jersey.spi.scanning.servlet.WebAppResourcesScanner.scan(WebAppResourcesScanner.java:79)
at com.sun.jersey.api.core.ScanningResourceConfig.init(ScanningResourceConfig.java:80)
at com.sun.jersey.api.core.servlet.WebAppResourceConfig.init(WebAppResourceConfig.java:102)
at com.sun.jersey.api.core.servlet.WebAppResourceConfig.<init>(WebAppResourceConfig.java:89)
at com.sun.jersey.api.core.servlet.WebAppResourceConfig.<init>(WebAppResourceConfig.java:74)
at com.sun.jersey.spi.container.servlet.WebComponent.getWebAppResourceConfig(WebComponent.java:668)
at com.sun.jersey.spi.container.servlet.ServletContainer.getDefaultResourceConfig(ServletContainer.java:435)
at com.sun.jersey.spi.container.servlet.ServletContainer.getDefaultResourceConfig(ServletContainer.java:602)
at com.sun.jersey.spi.container.servlet.WebServletConfig.getDefaultResourceConfig(WebServletConfig.java:87)
at com.sun.jersey.spi.container.servlet.WebComponent.createResourceConfig(WebComponent.java:699)
at com.sun.jersey.spi.container.servlet.WebComponent.createResourceConfig(WebComponent.java:674)
at com.sun.jersey.spi.container.servlet.WebComponent.init(WebComponent.java:205)
at com.sun.jersey.spi.container.servlet.ServletContainer.init(ServletContainer.java:394)
at com.sun.jersey.spi.container.servlet.ServletContainer.init(ServletContainer.java:577)
at javax.servlet.GenericServlet.init(GenericServlet.java:161)
at com.ibm.ws.webcontainer.servlet.ServletWrapper.init(ServletWrapper.java:332)
at com.ibm.ws.webcontainer.servlet.ServletWrapper.handleRequest(ServletWrapper.java:633)
at com.ibm.ws.webcontainer.servlet.ServletWrapper.handleRequest(ServletWrapper.java:475)
at com.ibm.ws.webcontainer.filter.WebAppFilterManager.invokeFilters(WebAppFilterManager.java:1161)
at com.ibm.ws.webcontainer.webapp.WebApp.handleRequest(WebApp.java:4869)
at com.ibm.ws.webcontainer.osgi.DynamicVirtualHost$2.handleRequest(DynamicVirtualHost.java:297)
at com.ibm.ws.webcontainer.WebContainer.handleRequest(WebContainer.java:997)
at com.ibm.ws.webcontainer.osgi.DynamicVirtualHost$2.run(DynamicVirtualHost.java:262)
at com.ibm.ws.http.dispatcher.internal.channel.HttpDispatcherLink$TaskWrapper.run(HttpDispatcherLink.java:955)
at com.ibm.ws.http.dispatcher.internal.channel.HttpDispatcherLink.ready(HttpDispatcherLink.java:341)
at com.ibm.ws.http.channel.internal.inbound.HttpInboundLink.handleDiscrimination(HttpInboundLink.java:471)
at com.ibm.ws.http.channel.internal.inbound.HttpInboundLink.handleNewRequest(HttpInboundLink.java:405)
at com.ibm.ws.http.channel.internal.inbound.HttpInboundLink.processRequest(HttpInboundLink.java:285)
at com.ibm.ws.http.channel.internal.inbound.HttpInboundLink.ready(HttpInboundLink.java:256)
at com.ibm.ws.tcpchannel.internal.NewConnectionInitialReadCallback.sendToDiscriminators(NewConnectionInitialReadCallback.java:174)
at com.ibm.ws.tcpchannel.internal.NewConnectionInitialReadCallback.complete(NewConnectionInitialReadCallback.java:83)
at com.ibm.ws.tcpchannel.internal.WorkQueueManager.requestComplete(WorkQueueManager.java:504)
at com.ibm.ws.tcpchannel.internal.WorkQueueManager.attemptIO(WorkQueueManager.java:574)
at com.ibm.ws.tcpchannel.internal.WorkQueueManager.workerRun(WorkQueueManager.java:929)
at com.ibm.ws.tcpchannel.internal.WorkQueueManager$Worker.run(WorkQueueManager.java:1018)
at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1160)
at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:635)
at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:820)
```

Only code change I made is replacing

```
import org.codehaus.jackson.map.ObjectMapper;
```

with

```
import com.fasterxml.jackson.databind.ObjectMapper;
```

Any thoughts on how to resolve this.

I am wondering if I have to update Jersey.

Comment: Though there is no straightway indication of incompatibility between jersey and jackson from logs but it is worth trying to upgrade jersey. Also, check answers to [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/47253750/what-are-the-jersey-versions-compatible-with-jackson-2-9-2)

Comment: Which Liberty features do you have installed/enabled?

Answer (score 1):

`org.codehaus.jackson` is an older version of Jackson.

`com.fasterxml.jackson` represents the new project and package.

Your server is using new version of `ObjectMapper` so if it do not work, consider to upgrade Jersey also

https://mvnrepository.com/artifact/org.glassfish.jersey.core/jersey-client

https://mvnrepository.com/artifact/org.glassfish.jersey.core/jersey-server

Tell me at comment if you have any issue ^^

Comment: @Smile As I mentioned in the end of my question .. I replaced import org.codehaus.jackson.map.ObjectMapper; with com.fasterxml.jackson.databind.ObjectMapper;. So it shouldn't be an issue right?

Comment: @javaMan Is this comment for me or @SoT? Did you check my comment on the question?

Comment: Soorry.. it is for @SoT. I checked your comment. I am tyring the suggestions from that link. Thanks

Comment: Hi @javaMan, I'm so sorry since did not read your question carefully. I've made an edit

Comment: @SoT I updated Jersey and ran into new issue: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/62398291/an-exception-occurred-while-scanning-class-and-annotation-data-the-exception-wa